# how can i get currency locale using ip address " request()->ip();"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel and I need the best package to get formations from IP address, I used laravel geo and laravel geoip but return null every time, please can you propose?

geoip :

```
$location = geoip()->getLocation();
```

geo :

```
$ip = request()->ip();
$countryCode = Geo::location()->ipCountry($ip);
```

Comment: i believe we are using the very same [laravel package](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/) but it works fine for me, im guessing maybe its because of your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Geoip should be a good option for you.
[Check the github repo from here](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip)

You can use this documentation to get started:
[Documentation](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/)

Looking at your code it would be something like this:

```
$ip = request()->ip(); 
$geoData = geoip($ip);
$country = $geoData['country'];
$currency = $geoData['currency'];
```